# Clearing cache of MHLazyTableImages

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I want to clear cache used by MHLazyTableImages for images when i changed images from server. but i am unable to find where it is storing that images. So Will you please guide me.

Answer (score 0):

for clearing your MHLazyTableImages cache write following code line...

```
[[MHImageCache sharedInstance] flushMemory];
```

OR

instead of MHLazyTableImages, you use `EGOImageView` from [EGOImageLoading](https://github.com/enormego/EGOImageLoading)

Comment: i check flushMemory only clears loaded images, but not from the cache